# what is the difference of -fPIE and -pie for compilers

Tags: android, build, compilation

Android forces devs to make `position-independent executable` and in order to that is necessary to put some flags on `CFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS`

However some places tell you to put `-fPIE -pie` some just `-fPIE` and they also disagree if putting on CFLAGS or LDFLAGS

i would like to know which are the right flags for `position-independent executable`